# Does playing wind instruments cause damage to the eyes overtime?

Tags: eye, opthalmology, glaucoma, intraocular-pressure-iop, valsalva-maneuver

Found some studies that investigated the IOP's relation to wind instrument playing:
[one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12362583_Effect_of_Wind_Instrument_Playing_on_Intraocular_Pressure) [two](http://www.jovr.org/article.asp?issn=2008-322X;year=2018;volume=13;issue=3;spage=224;epage=230;aulast=Lin) [three](https://www.aaojournal.org/article/S0161-6420(99)00015-9/fulltext).

I'm curious because I thought wind instrument playing (as over time it takes endurance to control air with the obturator muscle) will acutally lower IOP, as endurance exercises usually do. 
The authors claim that the valsalva maneuver increases IOP and practicing many hours a day may cause glaucomatous damage over time. 
Do you think there is some truth to this? Does wind instrument playing damage the eyes? and if so, what were the symptoms?